# How to design a fast download server in java with low CPU usage?

Tags: download, hdfs, cpu-usage

I am trying to design a server which downloads file from HDFS to client side. I am using java and my current design includes using input stream to fetch and download a file to client side. However if I try downloading 5 10Gb files concurrently, CPU usage shoots to 100%. How can I better design so that CPU usage remains low?

Answer (score 0):

Use multithread class to hold more than one download by time. You can split the files and let the GC free memory for downloaded file instance for you!